# sqlalchemy model instance with contains_eager submited as arg to ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, python-multithreading

I have two models as follows

```
class User(db.Model, CreatedAtMixin, ModifiedAtMixin):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class Balance(db.Model, ModifiedAtMixin):
     __tablename__ = "billing_balance"

     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

     user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
     user = db.relationship("User", backref=backref("balance", uselist=False))
```

I need to select some Balances with joined load of User to them (to minimize number of db queries) and process each balance asynchronously in non-blocking way.

Here's how i did it:

```
def pmap(fn, iterable, max_workers=20):

    def _ensure_arg_is_iterable(arg):

        if type(arg) in (list, tuple):
            return arg

        return (arg,)

    futures = []
    pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers)
    for params in iterable:
        futures.append(pool.submit(fn, *_ensure_arg_is_iterable(params)))
    return futures


def some_func(balance):
    print(balance.user)


def main():
    balances = db.session.query(Balance).outerjoin(
        User, Balance.user_id == User.id
    ).filter(
         # conditions
    ).options(
       contains_eager(Balance.user)
    )

    ready_to_process = []
    for balance in balances:
        some_irrelevant_method(balance)
        # print(balance.user)
        ready_to_process.append(balance)

    pmap(some_func, ready_to_process)
```

Problem is that `balance.user` is `None` in `some_func(balance)` as print statement  shows, unless I explicitly call `balance.user` in `main()`. Consequently, I can't call any method or get any attribute of `balance.user` in `some_func` without getting an AttributeError.

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem or hits about why it goes that way would be appreciated.